# Turning off warnings in swi-prolog

Tags: swi-prolog

How Can I turn off warnings in swi-prolog.

```
Clauses of XXX/AA are not together in the source-file
```

is very annoying.

Answer (score 11):

Instead, you could fix the warning.

The [discontiguous directive](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=discontiguous/1) is needed when the clauses of a static (compiled) predicate cannot be compiled as a single unit. This happens when the clause definitions are:

- Not contiguous
- Exceed the maximum number of clauses

Comment: In which system does this happen when the maximum number of clauses is reached? Never heard of that.

Comment: @false I don't think it is a problem anymore, but a long time ago SWI Prolog, at least, had this problem.

Comment: This question is still unanswered. Is it possible to turn off all warnings in SWI-Prolog so that only the errors are shown?

Comment: @AndersonGreen yes, with style_check

Answer (score 8):

You can turn off these warnings with [style_check](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=style_check/1) using `:-style_check(-discontiguous).`.

For example, you can also put off the warning about singleton variables with `:-style_check(-singleton).`