# How can I ask questions on a family tree in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm currently trying to learn how to use Prolog. I have `SWI-Prolog version 6.2.6` installed.

It seems to run:

```
?- 3<4.
true.

?- 4<3.
false.
```

As a first example, I was trying to implement the possibility of asking questions about a family tree. So I've started with this, stored in `family.pl`:

```
father(bob,danna).
father(bob,fabienne).
father(bob,gabrielle).
mother(alice,danna).
mother(alice,fabienne).
mother(alice,gabrielle).
father(charlie,ida).
father(charlie,jake).
mother(danna,ida).
mother(danna,jake).
father(edgar,kahlan).
mother(fabienne,kahlan).
father(hager,luci).
mother(gabrielle,luci).
male(X) :- father(X,_).
female(X) :- mother(X,_).
```

But when I try to load this with `consult(family).` I get:

```
?- consult(family).
Warning: /home/moose/Desktop/family.pl:7:
    Clauses of father/2 are not together in the source-file
Warning: /home/moose/Desktop/family.pl:9:
    Clauses of mother/2 are not together in the source-file
Warning: /home/moose/Desktop/family.pl:11:
    Clauses of father/2 are not together in the source-file
Warning: /home/moose/Desktop/family.pl:12:
    Clauses of mother/2 are not together in the source-file
Warning: /home/moose/Desktop/family.pl:13:
    Clauses of father/2 are not together in the source-file
Warning: /home/moose/Desktop/family.pl:14:
    Clauses of mother/2 are not together in the source-file
% family compiled 0.00 sec, 17 clauses
true.
```

I don't understand what is the problem here. I've found some results that mentioned that `-` cannot be used in identifiers, but I didn't use `-` in an identifier.

**Question 1**: What causes the Warning from above? How can I fix it?

But there are only warnings, so I've continued with

```
?- female(fabienne).
true.

?- male(fabienne).
false.
```

Ok, this seems to work as expected.

Then I've added

```
male(jake).
female(ida).
female(kahlan).
female(luci).
brother(X,Y):-
    male(X),
    (mother(Z,X)=mother(Z,Y);father(Z,X)=father(Z,Y)).
```

and tried:

```
?- brother(jake,ida).
false.
```

Why isn't this true?

**Question 2:** What is the problem with my `brother` rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373927/prolog-clauses-are-not-together-in-source-file).

As for the second, you're thinking in terms of functions instead of relations.

```
mother(Z,X) = mother(Z,Y)
```

is the same as saying `X = Y` because it compares two terms, without interpreting them. If you want `Z` to be the mother of both `X` and `Y`, you need a conjunction:

```
mother(Z, X), mother(Z, Y)
```

Comment: I thought `,` had to be read as `or`. What would I write if I wanted them to have different mothers? `mother(Z, X); mother(Z, Y)`?

Comment: @moose, the `;` is the OR in prolog. If you want to enforce X and Y to have different mothers, you wan to say, *mother(X, Mx), mother(Y, My), Mx \== My.* That is, `Mx` is the mother of `X`, AND `My` is the mother of `Y`, AND `Mx` and `My` are different.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. (accept for correct answer, +1 for your comment)

Answer (score 0):

the warrning can be fixed if you move all the father and mother declarations together (do not mix them)
In brother definition you use = and you should use a logical AND so use ,(comma)
also you need to tell prolog that jake is a male because he can't figure it out from those rules

I split the brother definition in 2 because is more clear and this is like a logical OR (the first definition is valid or the second one)

```
father(bob,danna).
father(bob,fabienne).
father(bob,gabrielle).
father(charlie,ida).
father(charlie,jake).
father(edgar,kahlan).
father(hager,luci).

mother(alice,danna).
mother(alice,fabienne).
mother(alice,gabrielle).

mother(danna,ida).
mother(danna,jake).
mother(fabienne,kahlan).
mother(gabrielle,luci).
male(jake).
male(X) :- father(X,_).
female(X) :- mother(X,_).

brother(X,Y):-
    male(X),
    mother(Z,X),mother(Z,Y).
brother(X,Y):-
    male(X),    
    father(Z,X),father(Z,Y).
```

For test run

```
brother(X,Y).
```

for more results you need to add who is male opr female for those childs like I did for jake